# SOAPFaultException when deploying a WAR file on WebLogic

Tags: java, weblogic

Can someone tell me why i am receing the following error?

SOAPFaultException (javax.xml.rpc.soap):
    SOAP Fault:javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException:
            null

```
Detail:
<detail>
        <jwErr:jwErrorDetail xmlns:jwErr="http://www.bea.com/2002/04/jwErrorDetail/">
          null
        </jwErr:jwErrorDetail>
      </detail>; nested exception is:
    javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException:
        null
```

Stack:
     at weblogic.webservice.core.ClientDispatcher.receive(ClientDispatcher.java:317)
     at weblogic.webservice.core.ClientDispatcher.dispatch(ClientDispatcher.java:147)
     at weblogic.webservice.core.DefaultOperation.invoke(DefaultOperation.java:473)
     at weblogic.webservice.core.DefaultOperation.invoke(DefaultOperation.java:459)
     at weblogic.webservice.core.rpc.StubImpl._invoke(StubImpl.java:306)
         Location:
            jar:file:/apps/casd3.4/system/lib/casman-stepwise-3.4_build_07.jar!/
                sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@f4a24a
    Classes:
        weblogic.webservice.core.ClientDispatcher
        weblogic.webservice.core.DefaultOperation
        javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException
        weblogic.webservice.core.rpc.StubImpl
        Location:
            jar:file:/apps/casd3.4/system/lib/webserviceclient-9.2.jar!/
                sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@f4a24a
-1: No such file or directory**strong text**

Comment: If you work for com.[CUSTOMER NAME] or a partner it is in your best interest to do a search and replace for the customer name before posting stack traces.

Comment: The lines of the stack trace that are containing com.CUSTOMER are still important - just replace 'your_company' with 'my_company' for example.  This looks like something is trying to hit a web service or has a web service included in it that is getting called for some reason while the deployment is going on.